# Error with Primary key column while inserting data with OLEDB Destination

Tags: ssis, oledb, bulkinsert

Hi I am working with SSIS 2008. I have one OLEDB source and OLEDB destination objects to move data from source to destination. My destination table has one primary column with data type uniqueidentifier and default value being set as newsequnetialid().

with a stored procedure there is no problem in inserting data to my destination table, my primary key column takes sql generated guid() without any issues. But when I try to insert in ssis using oledb destination it complains about my primary key columns that NULL value can not be inserted. Please see the attached image below for set up of my OLEDB destination. Identity column is not mapped to any source column.

[image]

Comment: so maybe don't insert NULL to PrimaryKey column and leave `ignore` if this don't work, you need to show probably procedure which works...

Comment: @Justin unchecking the "Keep Nulls" worked for me but Its not inserting all the records now. Its skipping records that have Null in any of the column.

Comment: Mark `Keep nulls` and show `Mappings` tab of OLE DB Destination, I'm saying that if in procedure works insert, you must try to do same and in OLE DB Destination... You need insert or not insert correct value to PrimaryKey column, now I don't see what you inserting in OLE DB D. If the procedure works you can show the procedure, there probably will be something useful.

Comment: I have no issues now.I think this question is already answered. Thanks @justin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unchecking "Keep Nulls" solved my problem. I mis understood this option. If checked then it will try to insert NULL in to columns that are not mapped with any of the source columns.